# Bot web scraping Python envia link errado para Telegram

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram-bot

Criei um bot que faz login em um site e captura alguns links de meu interesse e salvo esses links em uma lista.

Após capturar os links eu envio para o telegram utilizando a seguinte função:

```
 def sendmessage(msg):
        msg = ('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + login_data.token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + login_data.chat_ID +
               '&text=Nova Pesquisa Disponivel: ' + msg)
        response = requests.get(msg)
        print(response)
```

As informações como token, chat ID, estão em outro arquivo que eu chamo através do import.

Até ai tudo bem, consigo printar a lista de links e vejo que está tudo certo, porém o link que chega no telegram está **totalmente diferente** do capturado pelo programa.

Alguém sabe como posso corrigir?

Link capturado :https://enter.ipsosinteractive.com/landing/?p=QUEE6Q%2BwCxgruTthqH3hE0XG5Sq%2BudiaczWoGG6/ZZUGilW0A1y8MT2VKpGpJpWUBjLwlOS3fHu7g%2BQWHqB10UHeWK86EwUUvGOwP%2B8RYGE%3D&rType=350&id=346269c0-4c66-11ec-bcb5-8fce4c4f73c5&as=16

Link recebido pelo telegram:https://enter.ipsosinteractive.com/landing/?p=QUEE6Q+wCxgruTthqH3hE0XG5Sq+udiaczWoGG6/ZZUGilW0A1y8MT2VKpGpJpWUBjLwlOS3fHu7g+QWHqB10UHeWK86EwUUvGOwP+8RYGE=

Segue abaixo o código para conferência, Desde já agradeço.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import login_data
from time import sleep


def main():
    while True:
        surveys_list = []
        try:
            with requests.session() as session:
                url = 'https://www.ipsosisay.com/pt-br'
                secure_url = 'https://www.ipsosisay.com/pt-br/surveys'
                request = session.get(url, headers=login_data.headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
                login_data.login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
        except Exception as error:
            print('Houve um erro', error.__class__)
        try:
            request = session.post(url, data=login_data.login_data, headers=login_data.headers)
            request = session.get(secure_url)
            site = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
            site = BeautifulSoup(site.prettify(), 'html.parser')
        finally:
            surveys = site.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table_data'})
            survey_link = surveys.find_all('a')
            for link in survey_link:
                if link['href'] not in surveys_list:
                    surveys_list.append(link['href'])
        print(surveys_list)

        def sendmessage(msg):
            msg = ('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + login_data.token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + login_data.chat_ID +
                   '&text=Nova Pesquisa Disponivel: ' + msg)
            response = requests.get(msg)
            print(response)

        for survey in surveys_list:
            pesquisa = str(survey)
            sendmessage(pesquisa)
        sleep(3600)
        continue


main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar outra biblioteca para envio:

Você pode usar a biblioteca python-telegram-bot. Você precisa instalar a biblioteca usando o pip:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Em seguida, importe a biblioteca e use o seu token de API para criar uma instância do bot:

```
import telegram
bot = telegram.Bot(token='SEU_TOKEN_AQUI')
```

Para enviar uma mensagem de texto, use o método bot.send_message(chat_id, text), onde chat_id é o ID do chat do Telegram para o qual você deseja enviar a mensagem e text é a string que você deseja enviar.

Por exemplo:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id=12345678, text='Hello, World!')
```